# quarto blog with Nuxt js

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, quarto

I've a set of Jupyter Notebooks render as a quarto blog. Now I would like to host this blog with user authentication. I have Nuxt3 server running for user authentication. Now issue I'm facing is that how to render static html (generate using quarto) with Nuxt3.
I have tried putting the html files in public folder and it works but then the middleware (user authentication) doesn't apply to public folder.  I would appreciate it if you could point me to the right direction to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is quarto? Do not put it in `public` directory.

Comment: Quarto is a static site generator from Jupyter notebook. So, basically I have a set of html file and would like to make them accessible only to the authenticated users.

Comment: Nuxt is probably not the best tech for that one then. AstroJS is probably a better choice for that one. Or even just some vanilla JS.

Comment: Nuxt with strapi has an in-built user authentication system, so that's why I selected this combination. Is there any boilerplate for user authentication with AstroJS or VanillaJS?

Comment: Yeah but strapi with Nuxt is not HTML files into Nuxt. Maybe Nuxt Content can be hacked in such a way but it doesn't look like this is supported. As for Astro there is probably a thing already. Check on their website or ask on their Discord.